# Pretty print JSON with Spring 4

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a controller class that looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enter/two-factor/blacklist", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getBlacklist(int days) {
    List<Honey> honey = honeyService.fetchAllPings(days);
    List<Locate> locations = honeyService.parseDistinctLocations(honey);
    return GeneralUtil.convertToJson(locations);
}
```

The 'GeneralUtil.convertToJson()' method returns a pretty-print string with this code:

```
public static String convertToJson(List<Locate> locations){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json = "";
    try {
        json = gson.toJson(new Blacklist(locations));
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(json);
    String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
    System.out.println(prettyJsonString);
    return prettyJsonString;
}
```

However, when the page renders, the JSON is not pretty-printed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're overlooking the fact that `@ResponseBody` with a `String` return type will cause a `StringHttpMessageConverter` to write the value returned to the HTTP response body. This `HttpMessageConverter` will produce a `content-type` of `text/plain`. I believe browsers don't render new line characters or trim whitespace between them. Your pretty printing gets lost.

What you should do is register your own `GsonHttpMessageConverter` or `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which is set up to do pretty printing. Then change your handler method's return type to `List<Locate>` and return `locations` directly. These `HttpMessageConverter` implementations produce `application/json` which browsers should render literally.

(`Gson` and `ObjectMapper` instances are thread safe. There's absolutely no reason to reinstantiate those classes for every request.)